# Qual è il significato di "sino alla feccia" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Così ora, riguardo a Marta. Mentre era appena alle
>   prime battute il grande andante d’oro del mio innamoramento per lei, già dentro di me la desideravo refrattaria se non indegna, per prepararmi a disporre in anticipo i pretesti e gli svincoli della fuga di domani.
>   
>         
>   Ebbene, di quel che tacitamente speravo, l’Adelina,
>   come se lo facesse apposta, mi diede soddisfazione **sino
>   alla feccia**.

La mia domanda è sul senso dell'espressione "sino alla feccia" in questo testo. Alla voce "feccia" di parecchi dizionari ho trovato l'espressione ["bere il calice fino alla feccia"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/feccia) col significato di

> sopportare tutti i dolori fino all’estremo

ma questo non ha molto senso nel brano sopra citato.

Ecco un altro [uso della locuzione "fino alla feccia"](https://www.ilfoglio.it/articoli/2012/11/26/news/basta-mi-arrendo-staro-con-silvio-57639/?refresh_ce) che non fa riferimento a "bere" né a "vino":

> Sarà interessante stare dalla parte di Berlusconi con il voto, arma ormai genuinamente ludica. E **fino alla feccia**, almeno per chi come me ambisca a nulla, per chi gli abbia messo contro una piccola lista alle ultime politiche, per chi abbia come chi scrive la certezza, messa in pagina e dichiarata infinite volte a lettere vuoi ironiche vuoi chiare, che il ciclo di Berlusconi è finito, strafinito.

E si trova anche [qui](https://lucechesorge.org/2017/10/22/amore-amaro/):

> La sua nascita nella povera stalla di Betlemme è stata tutta amore per noi, ma amore amaro; la sua circoncisione con il versamento del primo sangue divino, è stata ancora amore amaro per noi; la sua fuga in Egitto, come un esiliato sotto minaccia di morte, è stata ancora amore amaro per noi; la vita trascorsa a Nazareth per circa trent’anni nel nascondimento e nel silenzio, nella povertà e nel sacrificio è stato ancora amore amaro per noi; le incomprensioni, le insidie e le persecuzioni degli scribi e dei farisei durante la sua vita pubblica sono state tutto amore amaro per noi e, infine, le sofferenze e le ignominie patite durante i giorni della sua Passione e Morte, con il tradimento di Giuda, il rinnegamento di Pietro, la fuga degli Apostoli, sono state ancora più amore amaro ***fino alla feccia*** per noi uomini da salvare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come hai visto, letteralmente la feccia è il fondo, il deposito del vino che si accumula nelle botti, e figuratamente è la parte peggiore di qualcosa: la società, un'esperienza etc.

Quindi direi che qui il narratore ci stia raccontando che l'Adelina gli diede soddisfazione fino in *fondo*, compiutamente (non conosco il romanzo di Bufalino, ma suppongo comportandosi effettivamente in modo “indegno”), e visto che ciò consiste in un comportamento negativo, il narratore sottolinea la cosa con un termine che indica appunto un “fondo”, ma sgradevole, da scartare.

Comment: Effettivamente, in seguito si racconta come Adelina spiega alcuni aspetti negativi di Marta.

Comment: Se non hai mai letto questo libro, secondo me si tratta di un capolavoro pieno di poesia, assolutamente raccomandabile (è la seconda volta che lo leggo).